# How to skip the locator which does not exist in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have around 50 rows in a page. But those items are in sequence.

The problem is when someone entered and deleted that table row. That id would not be there in page..

Example:

```
User added 1st record: id 101 added.
User added 2nd record: id 102 added
User added 3rd record: id 103 added.
```

If user deletes 2nd record, then two records would be there on the page but with id 101, 103.

I am trying to write that if that id is present then get the text else leave that in the for loop. I am getting only records till it found if that id is not found getting `NoSuchElementException` is displayed.

Please correct the code. But i want to the solution that if that id not exist, skip and run the else part.

```
for (int i = counterstart; i <= counterend; i++) {
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + i + "']/a")).isDisplayed()){
        System.out.println(i+" is present");
        String Projects = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + i + "']/a")).getText();
        System.out.println(Projects);           
    } else{
        System.out.println(i+" is NOT present");
    }
}
```

The exception that I get:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='7593']/a (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 503 milliseconds

Comment: If you're letting users edit and delete your data, how can you possibly write stable / deterministic tests or do proper asserts (rather than catching and ignoring exceptions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method isPresent instead of isDisplayed.

```
public boolean isPresent(WebElement e) {
    boolean flag = true;
    try {
        e.isDisplayed();
        flag = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: You call your method `isPresent` rather than `isDisplayed`, yet all you do is call `isDisplayed()` in a try block!

Answer (score 0):

```
How about this:

        for (int i = counterstart; i <= counterend; i++) {

            WebElement element;

            try{
                element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + i + "']/a"));
            }catch(NoSuchElementException n)
            {
                element = null;
            }

            if(element !=null){
                System.out.println(i+" is present");
                String Projects = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + i + "']/a")).getText();
                System.out.println(Projects);
            }else{
                System.out.println(i+" is NOT present");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all the parent of all the elements you want to get the text from and use it to drill down, this way you won't get the exception

Assuming the html looks like this

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="11">
    <a>text</a>
  </div>
  <div id="12">
    <a>text</a>
  </div>
  <div id="13">
    <a>text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can do this

```
// get all the elements with id
List<WebElement> ids = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#parent > div"));

// get all the texts using the id elements
for (WebElement id :ids) {
   String projects = id.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText();
   System.out.println(projects);
}
```